# Start Socket.IO server from PHP

Tags: php, socket.io, exec

I'm trying to start my Socket.IO server from PHP, and it fails to execute.
Node.js server works fine from a command line.
The code looks like this:

```
<?php
// this code only runs once when the site manager logs in
exec("/home/k4elo/public_html/node server.js", $output, $retval);
if ($retval == 0)
{
    echo $output[0];
}
    else
{
    echo "Error issuing exec command!";
}
?>
```

It always comes back echoing the error statement. I must be doing something wrong here.  Any ideas?

Comment: redirect the stderr and collect the stdout to see the error message, what does it says? I mean something like `exec("/home/k4elo/public_html/node server.js 2>&1" , $output, $retval);` then something like `echo "error.. ".$output`

Comment: Thanks DRC.  I changed it to exec("/home/k4elo/public_html/node server.js 2>&1>>err.log", $output, $retval);  The err.log file is created but empty :(

Comment: yeah but that's not what I said, is `$output` also empty? what about `$retval`?

Comment: ok, I see it now.  It looks at "node" and says no such file or directory.  So how can I get it to execute "node server.js"?

Answer (score 1):

probably something as simple as:

```
exec("/usr/bin/node /home/k4elo/public_html/server.js", $output, $retval);
```

Comment: glad it worked, please consider accepting the answer if that was useful.